# bcrypt - windows 10 x64 build error

Tags: node.js, npm, bcrypt

I have issue with bcrypt installation on windows 10 x64.

My installs:

```
node = 6.31
node-gyp = 3.4.0
npm = 3.10.3
python = 2.7.0
VSCommunity 2015
windows build tools
```

I have readed how to, with bcrypt package, based on node-gyp. I am really tired of fighting with this issue. I got error: (PS I tried with v0.8.6)

```
> bcrypt@0.8.6 install C:\Users\pi15463\www\BaaS\node_modules\bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\pi15463\www\BaaS\node_modules\bcrypt>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp                   (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_mo                  dules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,                   please add the "/m" switch.
  blowfish.cc
  bcrypt.cc
  bcrypt_node.cc
..\src\bcrypt.cc(232): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned                   char', possible loss of data [C:\Users\pi15463\www\BaaS\node_modules\bcrypt\bui                  ld\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
..\src\bcrypt_node.cc(76): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'ssize_t'                   to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data [C:\Users\pi15463\www\BaaS\node_module                  s\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
..\src\bcrypt_node.cc(229): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size                  _t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\pi15463\www\BaaS\node_modules\bcry                  pt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
..\src\bcrypt_node.cc(230): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size                  _t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\pi15463\www\BaaS\node_modules\bcry                  pt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
  win_delay_load_hook.c
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\src\win_delay_loa                  d_hook.c(34): error C2373: '__pfnDliNotifyHook2': redefinition; different type m                  odifiers [C:\Users\pi15463\www\BaaS\node_modules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj                  ]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\delayimp.h(134)                  : note: see declaration of '__pfnDliNotifyHook2'
```

Like you see a bounch of warns and no files at all. I saw some similar problems, but every1 has different configuration, so I decided to create a new thread.
Why on Ubuntu everything works ok, and on windows always are problems...

Hate my corporate pc.

Please for hints, and best regards!
Uland

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: windows10 pc and no way to get bcrypt installed.

I solved this by using **bcryptjs** (do not confuse it with bcrypt).

Basically bcryptjs does the same job as bcrypt but the former is written in pure js and has no cumbersome dependencies. The only downside is that it is 30% slower than bcrypt.

For me it worked right away.

here is the [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs) to the relevant page on the npmjs website: